# RestKit Mapping for different web services in different view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I am developing an iPad App. I have three different view controllers wherein I call three different web services using RestKit and map them to core data entity. I display the data in all view controllers by using NSFetchedResultsController.

First time when I try to load the data, it works correctly on all the view controllers. Later when I come up to the first view controller and try to load the data, it fails. I feel I am messing something.

Here is my code. In AppDelegate, I initialize RestKit:

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseURL];

//[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];
[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];

// Initialize managed object model from bundle
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];

// Initialize managed object store
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

// Complete Core Data stack initialization
[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];
NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"StockTakeDB.sqlite"];
NSString *seedPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"StoreItemsDB" ofType:@"sqlite"];
NSError *error;
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:seedPath withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];
NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);

// Create the managed object contexts
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

// Configure a managed object cache to ensure we do not create duplicate objects
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];

viewStockRestKitManagedObjectContext = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
takeStockRestKitManagedObjectContext = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
takeStockItemsByLocationRestKitManagedObjectContext = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
```

In the first view controller, I setup mapping and other required things as shown below:

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

// Initialize managed object model from bundle
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];

// Initialize managed object store
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

 //Complete Core Data stack initialization
[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];
NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"StockTakeDB.sqlite"];
NSString *seedPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"StoreItemsDB" ofType:@"sqlite"];
NSError *error;
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:seedPath withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];
NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);

// Create the managed object contexts
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

// Configure a managed object cache to ensure we do not create duplicate objects
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];

[objectManager addFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSURL *URL) {
    RKPathMatcher *pathMatcher = [RKPathMatcher pathMatcherWithPattern:viewStockRequestPath];

    NSDictionary *argsDict = nil;
    BOOL match = [pathMatcher matchesPath:[URL relativePath] tokenizeQueryStrings:NO parsedArguments:&argsDict];

    if (match) {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"StoreItems"];
        return fetchRequest;
    }

    return nil;
}];

RKEntityMapping *storeItemsListMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"StoreItems" inManagedObjectStore: managedObjectStore];
storeItemsListMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"itemId"];

[storeItemsListMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:
 @{
   @"itemId" : @"itemId",
   @"itemName" : @"itemName",
   @"itemCode" : @"itemCode",
   @"uomCode" : @"uomCode",
   @"locId" : @"locId",
   @"locName" : @"locName",
   @"subLocId" : @"subLocId",
   @"subLocName" : @"subLocName",
   @"storeItemId" : @"storeItemId"
   }
 ];

RKResponseDescriptor *storeItemsListResponseDescriptor =
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:storeItemsListMapping
                                             method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                        pathPattern:nil
                                            keyPath:nil
                                        statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:storeItemsListResponseDescriptor];
```

Then I am getting the Objects:

```
 [[RKObjectManager sharedManager]
 getObjectsAtPath:viewStockRequestPath
 parameters:nil
 success: ^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
     NSLog(@"requestDataItemsForStore - Mapping Success");
      NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"StoreItems"];

NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"locName" ascending:YES];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[descriptor];

NSError *error = nil;
[[appDelegate viewStockRestKitManagedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
      NSError *error;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
}
     [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
 failure: ^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     RKLogError(@"Load failed with error: %@", error);
     NSLog(@"requestDataItemsForStore - Loading Failed");
 }
 ];
```

and here is the fetchedresultscontroller code:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
if (viewStockFetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return viewStockFetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"StoreItems" inManagedObjectContext:[appDelegate viewStockRestKitManagedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSSortDescriptor *rackNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"locName" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[rackNameDescriptor];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
viewStockFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[appDelegate viewStockRestKitManagedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:@"locName" cacheName:nil];
viewStockFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
return viewStockFetchedResultsController;
```

}

In other view controller, I am calling different web service and mapping to different core data entity:

Here is the code in other view controller:

```js
 takeStockLocationWithStatusRequestPath = @"/stocktake/stocktake/1/usr/1/locwithstatus";
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
// Initialize managed object model from bundle
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
// Initialize managed object store
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
// Complete Core Data stack initialization
[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];
NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"StockTakeDB.sqlite"];
NSString *seedPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"StoreItemsDB" ofType:@"sqlite"];
NSError *error;
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:seedPath withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];
NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);
// Create the managed object contexts
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];
// Configure a managed object cache to ensure we do not create duplicate objects
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
[objectManager addFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSURL *URL) {
RKPathMatcher *pathMatcher = [RKPathMatcher pathMatcherWithPattern:takeStockLocationWithStatusRequestPath];
NSDictionary *argsDict = nil;
BOOL match = [pathMatcher matchesPath:[URL relativePath] tokenizeQueryStrings:NO parsedArguments:&argsDict];
if (match) {
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"RackStockTakeStatus"];
return fetchRequest;
}
return nil;
}];
RKEntityMapping *rackStockTakeStatusListMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"RackStockTakeStatus" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
rackStockTakeStatusListMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"stockTakeLocId"];
[rackStockTakeStatusListMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:
@{
@"stockTakeLocId" : @"stockTakeLocId",
@"stockTakeUuid" : @"stockTakeUuid",
@"locId" : @"locId",
@"locName" : @"locName",
@"status" : @"status",
@"stockTakeByUser" : @"stockTakeByUser",
@"stockTakeByUserId" : @"stockTakeByUserId",
@"beginTime" : @"beginTime",
@"percentCompleted" : @"percentCompleted"
}
];
RKResponseDescriptor *rackStockTakeStatusListResponseDescriptor =
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:rackStockTakeStatusListMapping
method:RKRequestMethodGET
pathPattern:nil
keyPath:nil
statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)
];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:rackStockTakeStatusListResponseDescriptor];
then getting the objects:
NSString *requestPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/stocktake/stocktake/%@/usr/1/locwithstatus",[defaults objectForKey:@"loggedInUserSelectedStoreId"]];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]
getObjectsAtPath:requestPath
parameters:nil
success: ^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RackStockTakeStatus" inManagedObjectContext:[appDelegate takeStockRestKitManagedObjectContext]];
[request setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
[[appDelegate takeStockRestKitManagedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSError *error;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
NSLog(@"requestDataItemsForStore - Mapping Success");
}
failure: ^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
RKLogError(@"Load failed with error: %@", error);
NSLog(@"requestDataItemsForStore - Loading Failed");
}
];
```

FetchedResultsController code:

```js
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    
    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RackStockTakeStatus" inManagedObjectContext:[appDelegate takeStockRestKitManagedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSSortDescriptor *rackNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"locName" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[rackNameDescriptor];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
   fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[appDelegate takeStockRestKitManagedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Can you help me to identify the issue?

Comment: Fails how? Because you're adding duplicate mappings? Or because you're switching out the object store? Centralise your setup so you don't do it repeatedly - i.e. don't put it in a view controller.

Comment: @Wain, when I switch the view controllers, it is somehow loading data which is required for other view controllers. I am not sure why exactly this happens. I don't think I have duplicate mapping, could you please point out the duplicate mapping?

Comment: What do you mean loading other VC data? You don't show any other VCs. Are you adding all the same mapping a in each VC? Making all the same requests? No predicates?

Comment: @Wain, Thank you for your response. I have updated the post to include the code in other VC. Your guidance will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that all of your response descriptors path patterns are nil. This means that all of the response descriptors will be applied to all responses. RestKit will create instances of whichever entity it's told to for a matching descriptor, it doesn't matter how many of the keys in the descriptor are found to map. So, you'll get a lot of partially populated instances of the wrong type created.

To fix, set the path pattern of each response descriptor to match the request URL path.

Comment: That seems to resolve the issue with data load. Now I am facing different in one of the vc. Application is crashing with the below error:

Comment: Here is the crash log:

I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'RackStockTakeStatus' by attributes 'stockTakeLocId'
 *** Assertion failure in -[RKEntityByAttributeCache addObjects:completion:], StockTake/Pods/RestKit/Code/CoreData/RKEntityByAttributeCache.m:333
 ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot add object with entity 'RackStockTakeStatus' to cache for entity of 'RackStockTakeStatus''

Comment: Please start a new question for that including the crash details, with full stack trace and the mapping and request code for that entity

Comment: Sure. Thank you so much for the resolving this.

Comment: No problem, and welcome to SO. Remember to tick and vote answers that help and solve :-) Actually I see you've been a member for a while, just not a big user :-)

Comment: Sure. Yes I am member for long time but I was posting lot of questions. Now I am trying to learn how SO works. I will contribute and become star user like you :)